# What could be an efficient way to migrate 1000 days of data with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm currently working on making a new server for my project.
There, I need to migrate data from original db to new server's db.

I was thinking of using loop to transfer datas and it worked until when it got to like day 700:
it started calling out `network socket disconnected before tls connection established`.

So I increased the timeout to 100k ms, and yet its quite shaky.

I've found that using cursor and stream could fix this problem, but no matter how many times I looked into documentations or other posts, I could not understand how I should implement them :(

Here's my code
**loop to migrate data**

```
exports.delayMigration = async(daysAgo, req, res, next) => {
  const delay = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 300));
  let queryDate = daysAgo
  
  const migrateData = async(queryDate) => {
    
    for (let i = queryDate || 0; i >= 0; i --) {
      await delay()
      try {
        let date = i
        console.log('migrating data on ' + new Date(moment().startOf('day').subtract(date, 'days').subtract(1, 'day')))
        finishedService(i)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  }
  migrateData(queryDate)
}
```

**inside migrateData function**

```
// connect to db 2
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectDB = async () => {
  const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.db2, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
  });
  console.log(`MongoDB connected ${conn.connection.name}`.bold.yellow.underline)
}

connectDB()

// connect to db 1
const makeNewConnection = require('../config/db');
const mainDB= makeNewConnection(process.env.db1)

<!-- then I import all models from db1 and db2-->
<!------------------------------------------------->

const finishedService = asyncHandler( async(daysAgo = 0) => { 
  
  const db1Data= await db1Model.find({
    checkedAt: { 
      $gte: new Date(queryDate),
      $lt: new Date(queryTo)
    }
  }).select('some model to populate')

  const db2Data= await db2Model.bulkWrite(
    db1Data.map((data) => ({
      updateOne: {
      filter: { service: data.service },
      update: { $set: sale },
      upsert: true
      }
    }))
  );    
})
```

Any tip of hint on optimizing this would be appreciate it!

Comment: Have you tried the database commands provided by MongoDB? You can create a backup of one database and then import that into the other one.

Comment: well, i thought about making back up clone of my database. But the purpose of making new db is so that I can modify my data in more useful way ... so inside my express app, I've applied some logics to reshape data and save them! @Patric